# pull с удаленного в измененный локальный репозиторий

Tags: git

У меня есть файлы которые не идентичны к файлам из репозитория удаленного. Как можно слить репозиторий себе в локальный , не изменив локальный, а добавив изменения из удаленного. Делал через 
git pull origin master:master, а потом по подсказке git reset --hard, я так понимаю оно удалит всё мое локальное и заменит удаленным.

Comment: Используйте ветки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

создайте временную ветку, например так `git checkout -b temp` - создаст ветку temp и перейдёт на неё. потом спульте туда нужный вам код `git pull origin temp`. в итоге у вас будет ваша основная ветка `master` с вашей разработкой и временная ветка `temp` со скачанным альтернативным кодом.

по итогу у вас будет две версии, которые необходимо объединить. если изменения в двух ветках затрагивают один и те же части файлов, то автоматически это сделать не получится, ведь программа не понимает, какая из этих версий вам подходит больше - подобные конфликты решаются вручную выбором нужного кода и удалением ненужного.

подробнее по ссылке: [Основы конфликтов при слиянии](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-Git-%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8)